# How to handle dynamic id from xpath

Tags: selenium, ide

I am trying to explore IDE with this site http://www.barnesandnoble.com/, by just recording and play back.

1.In the search box just enter any text to search,
2.Ten click on All Products, select Books.

When i record its xpath is as below

/html/body[@id='CDS']/div[@id='navContainer']/div[@id='bnnav2011']/div[@id='yui_3_3_0_1_1355746621091_93']/div[@id='bn-global-header']/div[@id='yui_3_3_0_1_1355746621091_92']/div[@id='yui_3_3_0_1_1355746621091_91']/form[@id='qs']/div[@id='yui_3_3_0_1_1355746621091_90']/div[@id='yui_3_3_0_1_1355746621091_89']/ul[@id='yui_3_3_0_1_1355746621091_88']/li[@id='yui_3_3_0_1_1355746621091_99']

But when we play ti again it gives error,[error] locator not found:
Wehn i search for its xpath , its chnaged and is as below

/html/body[@id='CDS']/div[@id='navContainer']/div[@id='bnnav2011']/div[@id='yui_3_3_0_1_1355748592221_91']/div[@id='bn-global-header']/div[@id='yui_3_3_0_1_1355748592221_97']/div[@id='yui_3_3_0_1_1355748592221_96']/form[@id='qs']/div[@id='yui_3_3_0_1_1355748592221_95']/div[@id='yui_3_3_0_1_1355748592221_94']/ul[@id='yui_3_3_0_1_1355748592221_93']/li[@id='yui_3_3_0_1_1355748592221_98']

Observe that, its ID's are changing.

Can any one tell me how to handle this ?

Comment: is this related to [tag:firefox] and [tag:selenium-ide]?

Comment: you should tag your question so people with knowledge in the right area take a look at your question!

Comment: Yes Alex, its related to selenium ide. I will take care next time for proper tag.

Answer (score 1):

The IDE is not very smart at generating XPath queries, in fact, there isn't an automated tool out there that will calculate a reliable XPath query. Why? The reason is because to generate the XPath query, it will walk down the tree from the top (at the `html` element), down to the element you are interacting with.

Whilst this is fine for a lot of things, if you have elements that have dynamic values (dynamic text/ID/name/classes or even if it changes position), it's never going to work.

You'll need to look at a different way to get it, so you'll have to override what the IDE is giving you.

Looking at the source, they give whatever is selected a class value of `ui-selectmenu-selected`. So when the page loads, the 'All Products' list item (`li`) will have that class, when you change the item the new item will have that class.

So you could use this XPath:

```
//li[@class='ui-selectmenu-selected']
```

Or, this CSS selector:

```
li.ui-selectmenu-selected
```

Or, use this XPath to get the 'All Products' item specifically. It will start one level up, using the actual menu, then go down and find the item:

```
//ul[@class='ui-selectmenu']/li[text()='All Products' and not(@class='ui-selectmenu-hidden')]
```

Comment: Hi Arran thnks a lot for your comment and sorry for being late reply. Today when recorded the same with IDE, its not recording it with ID, instead it recorded with    css as below   css=li.ui-selectmenu-hover and again failed to replay. Giving error '[error] Element css=li.ui-selectmenu-hover not found '.  I have Xpather installed . IS Firebug help in this case ?

Comment: Also Arran I am using xpather to find the element.I am getting the xpath with Id's ( Like   /html/body[@id='CDS']/div[@id='navContainer']/div[@id='bnnav2011']/div[@id='yui_3_3_0_1_1355746621091_93']/div[@id='bn-global-header']/div[@id='yui_3_3_0_1_1355746621091_92']/...) From where you found the xpath '//ul[@class='ui-selectmenu']/li[text()='All Products' and not(@class='ui-selectmenu-hidden')]
' ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using xpath: Position. It seems that the IDs are changing all the time.

Comment: I am new to Selenium. Will pls tell in details how to use it wit Position ?

Comment: When you view your action in Selenium, select it and you have a DOWN arrow at the right of the Command field. Select xpath: Position.

Comment: Hi Eric, yes with Position i am able to click the 'All Products' drop down. But then again it failed next time.

Comment: If everything else fails, use the ClickAt instead of Click. You need a stable locator, which you know doesn't change it's ID, like the header or the background. Then you have to add the coords from that locator. ClickAt uses (locator, coords).

Comment: clickAt(locator, coordString) 
Arguments:

locator : an element locator
coordString : specifies the x,y position (i.e. - 10,20) of the mouse event relative to the element returned by the locator.

Answer (score 0):

As an answer to your question you should move away from id's and try using xpath or css selectors where you can select the nth child of the parent. 
Since you are new to selenium I would like to point to my notes here at.-
http://selenium-testing-notes.blogspot.in/
it will help you through a lot of other pitfalls I fell in.
The best way I found to help with selectors is to work with firebug with firepath installed. This setup can help you verifying your xpath and css selectors.

Answer (score 0):

I saw your question based on that answer is first you need to add on fire-path in Firefox .Using firepath you can find the xpath locator. it is very simple to you

Example:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("see![image which i have attached in this question][1] the xpath path locator details").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Arran i am able to click the All Products button using the xpath you have given ( xpath= //ul[@class='ui-selectmenu']/li[text()='All Products' and not(@class='ui-selectmenu-hidden')]
 and also get the list available. But then not able to click the Books item from the Menu.